# incompatible pointer types initializing UITextView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a button for sharing the text of a 'Text View'. In Simulator and device, button working fine, but in Xcode editor, I am getting this error:

```
Incompatible pointer types initializing 'UITextView *' with an expression of type 'NSString *
```

Here is code.

```
(IBAction)shareButton:(id)sender 
{
    UITextView *myText = _texteditor.text;

    NSString *preText = @"Somthing to Write";   
    NSArray *objectsToShare = @[myText, preText];
    UIActivityViewController *activityVC = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:objectsToShare applicationActivities:nil];

    NSArray *excludeActivities = @[UIActivityTypeAirDrop,
                                   UIActivityTypeAssignToContact,
                                   UIActivityTypeSaveToCameraRoll,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToFlickr,
                                   UIActivityTypePostToVimeo];

    activityVC.excludedActivityTypes = excludeActivities;

    [self presentViewController:activityVC animated:YES completion:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know which class type is your _texteditor, but in textfield, textview or label the property 'text' is always a NSString type.

Change your first line with the right class type:

```
NSString *myText = _texteditor.text;
```

and the error disappear.